# struts2 validation for Dropdown

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, struts-validation

In a form i have stylish selectbox using dropkick plugin. 
How should i write a server side validation. I have tried with one hidden field,when i select any value from the selectbox i assigned the value to the hidden and

i wrote a server side validation for hidden field

my problem is 
when i click the submit button the valiation works but the dropdown not get selected

i have the structure

```
<div class="dk_options">
<ul class="dk_options_inner">
<li class="dk_option_current"><a data-dk-dropdown-value="">Select State</a></li>
<li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="1">AK</a></li>
<li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="2">AL</a></li>
<li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="3">AR</a></li>
<li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="4">AZ</a></li>
<li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="5">CA</a></li>
<li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="6">CO</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

how i write serverside validation for the dropdown selectbox. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Using your original select name in server side. For example,you page should be like this :

Html:

```
  <select name="color" class="change" tabindex="4">
          <option value="">Please select a color</option>
          <option value="#0084c7">Blue</option>
          <option value="#E15A01">Orange</option>
          <option value="#604A42">Brown</option>
  </select>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(function () {
   $('.change').dropkick();
 }
```

When you submit form, you can get parameter by name "color".

Server:

```
String color = request.getParameter("color");
```

Struts validation:

```
<validators>
    <field name="color">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <message key="requiredstring"/>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
</validators>
```

Comment: I don't have any problem in getting value.I want to use struts validation for that select box

Comment: there no different with text input, Updated it.